# Problem with "converting a string constant to 'char*'" in the WiFi library

Tags: iot

error:

```
C:\Users\mrtas\Desktop\sketch_may23a\sketch_may23a.ino: In function 'void setup()':

C:\Users\mrtas\Desktop\sketch_may23a\sketch_may23a.ino:41:24:
warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

   WiFi.begin(SSID, PASS);   //Begin WiFi
              ^     ^
```

code:

```
#include <DHT.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#define DHTTYPE DHT11
#define DHTPIN 5

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

String msg = "GET /update?key=TWE505JXFTXDPNB3";
float temp;
char SSID;
char Pass;

int hum;

String tempC;

int error;
void updateTemp();
#define SSID "wifi name"

#define PASS "wifi pass"

#define IP "184.106.153.149"

void setup()
{
  dht.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(10);

  // Connect to WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(SSID);
  WiFi.begin(SSID, PASS);     //Begin WiFi

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
}

void loop() {
start:
  error = 0;

  temp = dht.readTemperature();
  hum = dht.readHumidity();

  char buffer[10];
  tempC = dtostrf(temp, 4, 1, buffer);
  updateTemp();

  if (error == 1) {
    goto start;
  }
  delay(5000);
  String cmd = "AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"";
  cmd += IP;
  cmd += "\",80";
  Serial.println(cmd);
  delay(2000);

  if (Serial.find("Error")) {
    return;
  }
  cmd = msg ;
  cmd += "&field1=";
  cmd += tempC;
  cmd += "&field2=";
  cmd += String(hum);
  cmd += "\r\n";
  Serial.print("AT+CIPSEND=");
  Serial.println(cmd.length());

  if (Serial.find(">")) {
    Serial.print(cmd);
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");
    //Resend...
    error = 1;
  }

  Serial.println("AT+CWMODE=1");
  delay(2000);
}

boolean connectWiFi()
{
  String cmd = "AT+CWJAP=\"";
  cmd += SSID;
  cmd += "\",\"";
  cmd += PASS;
  cmd += "\"";
  Serial.println(cmd);
  delay(5000);

  if (Serial.find("OK")) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: We need the full error message, including the information where the compiler found the problem in your code. Please add that to your question

Comment: C:\Users\mrtas\Desktop\sketch_may23a\sketch_may23a.ino: In function 'void setup()':
C:\Users\mrtas\Desktop\sketch_may23a\sketch_may23a.ino:38:24: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
   WiFi.begin(SSID, PASS);     //Begin WiFi
                        ^


                          ^

Comment: 1. Please add the error message to the question (click on “edit”) rather than as a comment. 2. This looks suspiciously like an issue of the WiFi library that [was fixed five years ago](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/WiFi/commit/09051498d099f8126d4bc9f33837a0e5d1f4b5c0). What version of the library are you using?

Comment: that's a warning, not an error ... does the compilation actually abort?

Comment: WiFi.h and AT commands mix? what are you doing?

Comment: i am working on a iot project and i found the code online .I am trying to fix it piece by  piece but i am not an expert in coding ,this is my first project i am still a student so if you can help  i would really  appriciate it

Comment: What is your hardware setup? Do you have a link to the place where you found the code?

Comment: This is a software issue. Hardware is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

It's basically a bug in the library which is expecting "char *" when you are supplying "const char *.

You could work around it by changing:

```
#define SSID "wifi name"
#define PASS "wifi pass"
```

to:

```
char SSID [] =  "wifi name";
char PASS [] =  "wifi pass";
```

That makes them non-const so the error message should go away.

Not tested. But that is the general idea.